# cpufreq support for AMD 5350 on ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, amd-processor, cpufreq

On Debian 8 I was able to set cpu governor on a small computer with a AMD 5350 apu (kabini cpu).

now using ubuntu 17.04, kernel 4.10, i get:

```
no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
```

Any ideas why?

```
$ sudo cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:

... cutting because i can only post 30k chars...
CPU 3:
   vendor_id = "AuthenticAMD"
   version information (1/eax):
      processor type  = primary processor (0)
      family          = Intel Pentium 4/Pentium D/Pentium Extreme Edition/Celeron/Xeon/Xeon MP/Itanium2, AMD Athlon 64/Athlon XP-M/Opteron/Sempron/Turion (15)
      model           = 0x0 (0)
      stepping id     = 0x1 (1)
      extended family = 0x7 (7)
      extended model  = 0x0 (0)
      (simple synth)  = AMD A-Series / E-Series / G-Series / Opteron X1100 Series / Opteron X2100 Series (Steamroller KB-A1), 28nm
   miscellaneous (1/ebx):
      process local APIC physical ID = 0x3 (3)
      cpu count                      = 0x4 (4)
      CLFLUSH line size              = 0x8 (8)
      brand index                    = 0x0 (0)
   brand id = 0x00 (0): unknown
   feature information (1/edx):
      x87 FPU on chip                        = true
      virtual-8086 mode enhancement          = true
      debugging extensions                   = true
      page size extensions                   = true
      time stamp counter                     = true
      RDMSR and WRMSR support                = true
      physical address extensions            = true
      machine check exception                = true
      CMPXCHG8B inst.                        = true
      APIC on chip                           = true
      SYSENTER and SYSEXIT                   = true
      memory type range registers            = true
      PTE global bit                         = true
      machine check architecture             = true
      conditional move/compare instruction   = true
      page attribute table                   = true
      page size extension                    = true
      processor serial number                = false
      CLFLUSH instruction                    = true
      debug store                            = false
      thermal monitor and clock ctrl         = false
      MMX Technology                         = true
      FXSAVE/FXRSTOR                         = true
      SSE extensions                         = true
      SSE2 extensions                        = true
      self snoop                             = false
      hyper-threading / multi-core supported = true
      therm. monitor                         = false
      IA64                                   = false
      pending break event                    = false
   feature information (1/ecx):
      PNI/SSE3: Prescott New Instructions     = true
      PCLMULDQ instruction                    = true
      64-bit debug store                      = false
      MONITOR/MWAIT                           = true
      CPL-qualified debug store               = false
      VMX: virtual machine extensions         = false
      SMX: safer mode extensions              = false
      Enhanced Intel SpeedStep Technology     = false
      thermal monitor 2                       = false
      SSSE3 extensions                        = true
      context ID: adaptive or shared L1 data  = false
      FMA instruction                         = false
      CMPXCHG16B instruction                  = true
      xTPR disable                            = false
      perfmon and debug                       = false
      process context identifiers             = false
      direct cache access                     = false
      SSE4.1 extensions                       = true
      SSE4.2 extensions                       = true
      extended xAPIC support                  = false
      MOVBE instruction                       = true
      POPCNT instruction                      = true
      time stamp counter deadline             = false
      AES instruction                         = true
      XSAVE/XSTOR states                      = true
      OS-enabled XSAVE/XSTOR                  = true
      AVX: advanced vector extensions         = true
      F16C half-precision convert instruction = true
      RDRAND instruction                      = false
      hypervisor guest status                 = false
   cache and TLB information (2):
   processor serial number: 0070-0F01-0000-0000-0000-0000
   MONITOR/MWAIT (5):
      smallest monitor-line size (bytes)       = 0x40 (64)
      largest monitor-line size (bytes)        = 0x40 (64)
      enum of Monitor-MWAIT exts supported     = true
      supports intrs as break-event for MWAIT  = true
      number of C0 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C1 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C2 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C3 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C4 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C5 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C6 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
      number of C7 sub C-states using MWAIT    = 0x0 (0)
   Thermal and Power Management Features (6):
      digital thermometer                     = false
      Intel Turbo Boost Technology            = false
      ARAT always running APIC timer          = false
      PLN power limit notification            = false
      ECMD extended clock modulation duty     = false
      PTM package thermal management          = false
      HWP base registers                      = false
      HWP notification                        = false
      HWP activity window                     = false
      HWP energy performance preference       = false
      HWP package level request               = false
      HDC base registers                      = false
      digital thermometer thresholds          = 0x0 (0)
      ACNT/MCNT supported performance measure = true
      ACNT2 available                         = false
      performance-energy bias capability      = false
   extended feature flags (7):
      FSGSBASE instructions                    = false
      IA32_TSC_ADJUST MSR supported            = false
      SGX: Software Guard Extensions supported = false
      BMI instruction                          = true
      HLE hardware lock elision                = false
      AVX2: advanced vector extensions 2       = false
      FDP_EXCPTN_ONLY                          = false
      SMEP supervisor mode exec protection     = false
      BMI2 instructions                        = false
      enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB                 = false
      INVPCID instruction                      = false
      RTM: restricted transactional memory     = false
      QM: quality of service monitoring        = false
      deprecated FPU CS/DS                     = false
      intel memory protection extensions       = false
      PQE: platform quality of service enforce = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      RDSEED instruction                       = false
      ADX instructions                         = false
      SMAP: supervisor mode access prevention  = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      CLFLUSHOPT instruction                   = false
      CLWB instruction                         = false
      Intel processor trace                    = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      SHA instructions                         = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      PREFETCHWT1                              = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      UMIP: user-mode instruction prevention   = false
      PKU protection keys for user-mode        = false
      OSPKE CR4.PKE and RDPKRU/WRPKRU          = false
      BNDLDX/BNDSTX MAWAU value in 64-bit mode = 0x0 (0)
      RDPID: read processor D supported        = false
      SGX_LC: SGX launch config supported      = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
   Direct Cache Access Parameters (9):
      PLATFORM_DCA_CAP MSR bits = 0
   Architecture Performance Monitoring Features (0xa/eax):
      version ID                               = 0x0 (0)
      number of counters per logical processor = 0x0 (0)
      bit width of counter                     = 0x0 (0)
      length of EBX bit vector                 = 0x0 (0)
   Architecture Performance Monitoring Features (0xa/ebx):
      core cycle event not available           = false
      instruction retired event not available  = false
      reference cycles event not available     = false
      last-level cache ref event not available = false
      last-level cache miss event not avail    = false
      branch inst retired event not available  = false
      branch mispred retired event not avail   = false
   Architecture Performance Monitoring Features (0xa/edx):
      number of fixed counters    = 0x0 (0)
      bit width of fixed counters = 0x0 (0)
   XSAVE features (0xd/0):
      XCR0 lower 32 bits valid bit field mask = 0x00000007
      XCR0 upper 32 bits valid bit field mask = 0x00000000
         XCR0 supported: x87 state            = true
         XCR0 supported: SSE state            = true
         XCR0 supported: AVX state            = true
         XCR0 supported: MPX BNDREGS          = false
         XCR0 supported: MPX BNDCSR           = false
         XCR0 supported: AVX-512 opmask       = false
         XCR0 supported: AVX-512 ZMM_Hi256    = false
         XCR0 supported: AVX-512 Hi16_ZMM     = false
         IA32_XSS supported: PT state         = false
         XCR0 supported: PKRU state           = false
      bytes required by fields in XCR0        = 0x00000340 (832)
      bytes required by XSAVE/XRSTOR area     = 0x00000340 (832)
   XSAVE features (0xd/1):
      XSAVEOPT instruction                        = true
      XSAVEC instruction                          = false
      XGETBV instruction                          = false
      XSAVES/XRSTORS instructions                 = false
      SAVE area size in bytes                     = 0x00000000 (0)
      IA32_XSS lower 32 bits valid bit field mask = 0x00000000
      IA32_XSS upper 32 bits valid bit field mask = 0x00000000
   AVX/YMM features (0xd/2):
      AVX/YMM save state byte size             = 0x00000100 (256)
      AVX/YMM save state byte offset           = 0x00000240 (576)
      supported in IA32_XSS or XCR0            = XCR0 (user state)
      64-byte alignment in compacted XSAVE     = false
   extended processor signature (0x80000001/eax):
      family/generation = AMD Athlon 64/Opteron/Sempron/Turion (15)
      model             = 0x0 (0)
      stepping id       = 0x1 (1)
      extended family   = 0x7 (7)
      extended model    = 0x0 (0)
      (simple synth) = AMD A-Series / E-Series / G-Series / Opteron X1100 Series / Opteron X2100 Series (Steamroller KB-A1), 28nm
   extended feature flags (0x80000001/edx):
      x87 FPU on chip                       = true
      virtual-8086 mode enhancement         = true
      debugging extensions                  = true
      page size extensions                  = true
      time stamp counter                    = true
      RDMSR and WRMSR support               = true
      physical address extensions           = true
      machine check exception               = true
      CMPXCHG8B inst.                       = true
      APIC on chip                          = true
      SYSCALL and SYSRET instructions       = true
      memory type range registers           = true
      global paging extension               = true
      machine check architecture            = true
      conditional move/compare instruction  = true
      page attribute table                  = true
      page size extension                   = true
      multiprocessing capable               = false
      no-execute page protection            = true
      AMD multimedia instruction extensions = true
      MMX Technology                        = true
      FXSAVE/FXRSTOR                        = true
      SSE extensions                        = true
      1-GB large page support               = true
      RDTSCP                                = true
      long mode (AA-64)                     = true
      3DNow! instruction extensions         = false
      3DNow! instructions                   = false
   extended brand id (0x80000001/ebx):
      raw     = 0x10000000 (268435456)
      BrandId = 0x0 (0)
   AMD feature flags (0x80000001/ecx):
      LAHF/SAHF supported in 64-bit mode     = true
      CMP Legacy                             = true
      SVM: secure virtual machine            = true
      extended APIC space                    = true
      AltMovCr8                              = true
      LZCNT advanced bit manipulation        = true
      SSE4A support                          = true
      misaligned SSE mode                    = true
      3DNow! PREFETCH/PREFETCHW instructions = true
      OS visible workaround                  = true
      instruction based sampling             = true
      XOP support                            = false
      SKINIT/STGI support                    = true
      watchdog timer support                 = true
      lightweight profiling support          = false
      4-operand FMA instruction              = false
      NodeId MSR C001100C                    = false
      TBM support                            = false
      topology extensions                    = true
   brand = "AMD Athlon(tm) 5350 APU with Radeon(tm) R3     "
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x8 (8)
      instruction associativity = 0xff (255)
      data # entries            = 0x8 (8)
      data associativity        = 0xff (255)
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x20 (32)
      instruction associativity = 0xff (255)
      data # entries            = 0x28 (40)
      data associativity        = 0xff (255)
   L1 data cache information (0x80000005/ecx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x40 (64)
      lines per tag     = 0x1 (1)
      associativity     = 0x8 (8)
      size (KB)         = 0x20 (32)
   L1 instruction cache information (0x80000005/edx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x40 (64)
      lines per tag     = 0x1 (1)
      associativity     = 0x2 (2)
      size (KB)         = 0x20 (32)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x100 (256)
      data associativity        = 2-way (2)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x200 (512)
      instruction associativity = 4-way (4)
      data # entries            = 0x200 (512)
      data associativity        = 4-way (4)
   L2 unified cache information (0x80000006/ecx):
      line size (bytes) = 0x40 (64)
      lines per tag     = 0x1 (1)
      associativity     = 16-way (8)
      size (KB)         = 0x800 (2048)
   L3 cache information (0x80000006/edx):
      line size (bytes)     = 0x0 (0)
      lines per tag         = 0x0 (0)
      associativity         = L2 off (0)
      size (in 512KB units) = 0x0 (0)
   Advanced Power Management Features (0x80000007/edx):
      temperature sensing diode      = true
      frequency ID (FID) control     = false
      voltage ID (VID) control       = false
      thermal trip (TTP)             = true
      thermal monitor (TM)           = true
      software thermal control (STC) = false
      100 MHz multiplier control     = true
      hardware P-State control       = true
      TscInvariant                   = true
   Physical Address and Linear Address Size (0x80000008/eax):
      maximum physical address bits         = 0x28 (40)
      maximum linear (virtual) address bits = 0x30 (48)
      maximum guest physical address bits   = 0x0 (0)
   Logical CPU cores (0x80000008/ecx):
      number of CPU cores - 1 = 0x3 (3)
      ApicIdCoreIdSize        = 0x3 (3)
   SVM Secure Virtual Machine (0x8000000a/eax):
      SvmRev: SVM revision = 0x1 (1)
   SVM Secure Virtual Machine (0x8000000a/edx):
      nested paging                 = true
      LBR virtualization            = true
      SVM lock                      = true
      NRIP save                     = true
      MSR based TSC rate control    = true
      VMCB clean bits support       = false
      flush by ASID                 = true
      decode assists                = true
      SSSE3/SSE5 opcode set disable = false
      pause intercept filter        = true
      pause filter threshold        = true
   NASID: number of address space identifiers = 0x8 (8):
   L1 TLB information: 1G pages (0x80000019/eax):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 TLB information: 1G pages (0x80000019/ebx):
      instruction # entries     = 0x0 (0)
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data # entries            = 0x0 (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   SVM Secure Virtual Machine (0x8000001a/eax):
      128-bit SSE executed full-width = true
      MOVU* better than MOVL*/MOVH*   = true
   Instruction Based Sampling Identifiers (0x8000001b/eax):
      IBS feature flags valid              = true
      IBS fetch sampling                   = true
      IBS execution sampling               = true
      read write of op counter             = true
      op counting mode                     = true
      branch target address reporting      = true
      IbsOpCurCnt and IbsOpMaxCnt extend 7 = true
      invalid RIP indication supported     = true
   Lightweight Profiling Capabilities: Availability (0x8000001c/eax):
      lightweight profiling                  = false
      LWPVAL instruction                     = false
      instruction retired event              = false
      branch retired event                   = false
      DC miss event                          = false
      core clocks not halted event           = false
      core reference clocks not halted event = false
      interrupt on threshold overflow        = false
   Lightweight Profiling Capabilities: Supported (0x8000001c/edx):
      lightweight profiling                  = false
      LWPVAL instruction                     = false
      instruction retired event              = false
      branch retired event                   = false
      DC miss event                          = false
      core clocks not halted event           = false
      core reference clocks not halted event = false
      interrupt on threshold overflow        = false
   Lightweight Profiling Capabilities (0x8000001c/ebx):
      LWPCB byte size             = 0x0 (0)
      event record byte size      = 0x0 (0)
      maximum EventId             = 0x0 (0)
      EventInterval1 field offset = 0x0 (0)
   Lightweight Profiling Capabilities (0x8000001c/ecx):
      latency counter bit size          = 0x0 (0)
      data cache miss address valid     = false
      amount cache latency is rounded   = 0x0 (0)
      LWP implementation version        = 0x0 (0)
      event ring buffer size in records = 0x0 (0)
      branch prediction filtering       = false
      IP filtering                      = false
      cache level filtering             = false
      cache latency filteing            = false
   Cache Properties (0x8000001d):
      --- cache 0 ---
      type                            = data (1)
      level                           = 0x1 (1)
      self-initializing               = true
      fully associative               = false
      extra cores sharing this cache  = 0x0 (0)
      line size in bytes              = 0x3f (63)
      physical line partitions        = 0x0 (0)
      number of ways                  = 0x7 (7)
      number of sets                  = 63
      write-back invalidate           = false
      cache inclusive of lower levels = false
      --- cache 1 ---
      type                            = instruction (2)
      level                           = 0x1 (1)
      self-initializing               = true
      fully associative               = false
      extra cores sharing this cache  = 0x0 (0)
      line size in bytes              = 0x3f (63)
      physical line partitions        = 0x0 (0)
      number of ways                  = 0x1 (1)
      number of sets                  = 255
      write-back invalidate           = false
      cache inclusive of lower levels = false
      --- cache 2 ---
      type                            = unified (3)
      level                           = 0x2 (2)
      self-initializing               = true
      fully associative               = false
      extra cores sharing this cache  = 0x3 (3)
      line size in bytes              = 0x3f (63)
      physical line partitions        = 0x0 (0)
      number of ways                  = 0xf (15)
      number of sets                  = 2047
      write-back invalidate           = false
      cache inclusive of lower levels = true
   extended APIC ID = 3
   Extended APIC ID (0x8000001e/ebx):
      compute unit ID            = 0x3 (3)
      cores per compute unit - 1 = 0x0 (0)
   Extended APIC ID (0x8000001e/ecx):
      node ID             = 0x0 (0)
      nodes per processor = 1 node (0)
   (instruction supported synth):
      CMPXCHG8B                = true
      conditional move/compare = true
      PREFETCH/PREFETCHW       = true
   (multi-processing synth): multi-core (c=4)
   (multi-processing method): AMD
   (APIC widths synth): CORE_width=2 SMT_width=0
   (APIC synth): PKG_ID=0 CORE_ID=3 SMT_ID=0
   (synth) = AMD A-Series / E-Series / G-Series / Opteron X1100 Series / Opteron X2100 Series (Steamroller KB-A1), 28nm
```

and

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 22
model           : 0
model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) 5350 APU with Radeon(tm) R3
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x700010b
cpu MHz         : 2050.145
cache size      : 2048 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_l2 hw_pstate proc_feedback vmmcall bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov
bugs            : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips        : 4100.29
TLB size        : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate proc_feedback
```

and

```
# modprobe msr
# cpufreq-aperf
CPU     Average freq(KHz)       Time in C0      Time in Cx      C0 percentage
000     [offline]
001     [offline]
002     [offline]
003     [offline]

000     [offline]
001     [offline]
002     [offline]
003     [offline]
```

...it goes like that forever.

and the most promising:

```
# cpupower monitor
    |Mperf               
CPU | C0   | Cx   | Freq 
   0|  0.67| 99.33|  1452
   1|  0.87| 99.13|   989
   2|  3.92| 96.08|  1177
   3|  0.94| 99.06|   983
```

The redhat user guide tells to load the drivers for cpu freq from `/lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/cpufreq/` but i don't have that. Only dir inside `...myarch/kernel/cpu/` is `mcheck`. Here is what i have loaded anyway:

```
# lsmod | grep amd
amd_freq_sensitivity    16384  0
edac_mce_amd           28672  0
amdgpu               1564672  0
amdkfd                139264  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
ttm                    98304  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_kms_helper        151552  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm                   352256  10 amdgpu,radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

Answer (score 1):

same cpu, here is my dmeg (too big for a comment)

```
$ grep -i cpu x
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 4 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:4 nr_cpu_ids:4 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 36 pages/cpu @ffff8aca3fc00000 s107992 r8192 d31272 u524288
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s107992 r8192 d31272 u524288 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 2 3 
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8192 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=64, nr_cpu_ids=4
[    0.018110] CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
[    0.018112] CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
[    0.018114] mce: CPU supports 6 MCE banks
[    0.195648] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Athlon(tm) 5350 APU with Radeon(tm) R3 (family: 0x16, model: 0x0, stepping: 0x1)
[    0.196893] NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPUs, permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.196923] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.197103] .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1 #2 #3
[    0.204348] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.227420] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.243432] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    1.753094] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.765606] microcode: CPU0: patch_level=0x0700010b
[    1.765615] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x0700010b
[    1.765625] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x0700010b
[    1.765634] microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x0700010b
[    1.790580] powernow_k8: This CPU is not supported anymore, using acpi-cpufreq instead.
[    1.969576] CU CPU: cores=4 id_base=0
[    1.973972] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 524288, num gpu pages 524288
[    1.998341] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8aca2f65cc00
[    1.998343] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8aca2f65cc04
[    1.998346] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8aca2f65cc08
[    1.998348] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8aca2f65cc0c
[    1.998350] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8aca2f65cc10
[    1.999258] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000078d30 and cpu addr 0xffff9da781438d30
[    1.999590] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c18 and cpu addr 0xffff8aca2f65cc18
[    1.999592] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c1c and cpu addr 0xffff8aca2f65cc1c
```